# Remotely control an Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have 50 virtual machines running using oracle virtualbox tool. Maintaining them has become really difficult. So I would like to create a small webpage or an app that will control these virtual machines. Basically to reboot, push files to these machines, pull files, shutdown or perform any operations in these VMs remotely using the tool/webpage I develop. Is that really possible. What kind of API does this comes with? I only know Java language. Is that enough?

Or if there are any other alternatives please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but would be a difficult job ! Specially pushing and pulling files from VM. You need to know some scripting languages. And in industry developers often prefer Python over Java to develop this kind of virtual machine applications. You can use this [Remote Desktop Connection Manager](http://remotedesktopmanager.com/Home/Download)

It may not fulfill all your requirements but can help you to achieve most of them.